# boto3 to automate getting info from all AWS account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, boto3

I am using Python boto 3 to get info on one of my AWS account. Can I automate it such a way that I can get the same info from all accounts? I know the boto 3 lib reads creds from the credentials file but can I have multiple credentials read?

Comment: Your credentials file can specify multiple profiles, or you can use `assume-role` to attain permissions on another account

Answer (score 2):

Boto3 can read credentials in many [different ways](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

One option is to have a credential file with a profile for each of your accounts (as mentioned in the comment by @jordanm) like this (examples from the [AWS documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#shared-credentials-file)):

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_secret_access_key=bar

[dev]
aws_access_key_id=foo2
aws_secret_access_key=bar2

[prod]
aws_access_key_id=foo3
aws_secret_access_key=bar3
```

And select the profile you want in the code, like this (again, from the [AWS documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#shared-credentials-file)):

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
# Any clients created from this session will use credentials
# from the [dev] section of ~/.aws/credentials.
dev_s3_client = session.client('s3')
```

Now you just need to loop through all your profiles.